# Editing Rust questions/answers to reflect the fact they only apply to a deprecated version

Tags: discussion, edits, old-questions

The Rust programming language ([rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust)) is [approaching the 1.0 release](http://blog.rust-lang.org/2015/02/13/Final-1.0-timeline.html) soon.

(Who am I? Huon Wilson, member of [the Rust core team](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-wiki-backup/blob/master/Note-core-team.md), and the [current top user](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/topusers) for [rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust).)

This release comes after a long period of pre-alpha, alpha, and (soon) beta development in public. Along the way, there have been huge changes to the language and library, meaning that it is very likely that code from 6 months ago (let alone 3 years) won't compile with a current compiler, or with the 1.0 release. In fact, there have been many major fundamental changes so even the concepts in many of the older answers are now irrelevant e.g. [the oldest question tagged [rust]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3210025/what-is-typestate) refers to a feature that used to be one of the major draw-cards of Rust, but no longer exists in the language at all.

These changes have caused endless difficulties for beginners trying to learn Rust: code that is outdated and irrelevant doesn't help. This is of course a general problem with Rust code on the internet, in blogs posts etc, but SO is a big source of help to many people, and the outdated code in [rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust) is something we can possible tackle.

Much of the active Rust community (e.g. people on IRC, publishing on crates.io) run the current nightlies, and there's not many active users of even the most recent release (alpha-2), let alone older releases. This will hold true at 1.0: people will move to either the stable 1.0 release or the post-1.0 nightlies. It is very unlikely that anyone will be trying to actively use older versions of the compiler. The point being: out-dated [rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust) answers won't help Rust users after 1.0, and are actively unhelpful for new users.

## proposal

I would like to give incoming users more help to avoid being tricked by old answers. I propose that

- questions and (accepted) answers with a small number of upvotes are edited to include a generic message at the top. Something along the lines of

  > ### This [question/answer] relates to a pre-1.0 version of Rust; it may be too old to be helpful.
  >
  > <sup>(NB. this message was inserted automatically for the lead-up to Rust 1.0. [link to more info].)</sup>

  In the best case, this would be done with automation, but I guess it's not out of the question for it to be done manually by a dedicated group of volunteers.
- more popular questions/answers get special attention, either inserting a more specific message like the above, and/or carefully updating the post to ensure that the correct modern way is clear e.g. linking to a newer question/answer that solves the problem (including possibly creating that answer, by posting a new answer to the same question), or editing the content in the accepted answer (especially if only a few minor code changes are required).

There is a lot of space for finessing exactly how this is done. I am currently thinking that we might do the above to the [~40%](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/286756/count-of-old-posts-by-tag?Tag=rust&MonthsOld=6) of [rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust) posts that are older than 6 months soon, and then the more recent posts closer to 1.0 (possibly in several stages). Similarly, the thresholds for popularity are pretty loose; I'm thinking questions with 3 or more upvotes, or questions with accepted answers with 5 or more upvotes, but that still [leaves several hundred posts to consider](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/286758/count-of-question-answer-combos-with-many-upvotes-by-tag?tag=rust&QScore=3&AScore=5).

Is this at all reasonable? If so, what is the best way to accomplish it? Are there alternate ways to solve the fundamental problem that work too?

## analysis

Using upvotes as a proxy for how popular/useful an answer is (and with some great assistance from @Manishearth) I looked at the distribution of [the accepted answers on [rust] questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/286757/distribution-of-accepted-answer-score-for-tag?tag=rust) and the distribution of [the questions themselves](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/286747/distribution-of-question-score-for-tag?tag=rust#resultSets) . It seems that most answers are not very useful: more than 40% have 2 or fewer votes. Similarly, more than half of questions get at most one vote.

Comment: Editing rusty questions ?

Comment: Another potential solution that we can implement today would be to tag all current Rust questions with something like `rust-prerelease`. That tag wiki could explain the same things. It's not nearly as nice as a big banner though.

Comment: @Shepmaster I agree that is a sensible addition, but I think it is a little subtle by itself (especially for people unfamiliar with SO's details).

Comment: Disclaiming my ignorance, I've never heard of rust (I really mean no offense). So I would disagree with `It seems that most answers are not very useful: more than 40% have 2 or fewer votes.` Isn't this kind of a inevitable side-effect of a somewhat niche (1700 questions) tag such as [rust]? Wouldn't two votes be considered as acceptably useful?

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier, other tags like java, c++, c have a similar distribution. Although, I'm not at all attached to those numbers. The main point of this post is trying to assess a reasonable strategy to mark the huge number of answers as obsolete to avoid confusion, the precise details can be worked out later. :)

Comment: @huon-dbaupp: Should we take the opportunity to clean up as well? I am afraid that because of the low bandwidth of Rust questions, a number of duplicates/quasi-duplicates/typos questions may have slipped through.

Comment: You could go further than Shepmaster's idea (at least, I think... not familiar enough with retagging details) and actually *replace* the current `rust` tag with `rust-prerelease` or `rust-obsolete` (or some mixture of both depending on question age), then create a brand new `rust` tag with no questions on the day of 1.0.

Comment: @MatthieuM., that would be a nice thing to do, but I think there's probably already enough work here. :)

Comment: I'll selfishly say that I'm not enthusiastic about @Leushenko's idea to retag - I'd rather not lose my status in the Rust tag and be forced to start again ^_^. Simply adding tags avoids that problem.

Comment: I've created [tag:rust-obsolete].

Answer (score 14):

Could version tags not be introduced [rust-0.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust-0.6) [rust-0.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust-0.5) etc to show the question (and subsequent answers) apply only to a pre beta version of [rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust) to avoid confusion?

Comment: I think this is exactly what's intended by the version tags.  Make it clear in the tag wiki excerpt that questions asked about [tag:rust-0.6] will often not apply to [tag:rust-1.0].

Comment: This is effectively what @Shepmaster suggested in the comments, as I said there, I think it would be best combined with another approach since it is quite subtle, especially for people unfamiliar with SO, and, it won't be seen at all by a direct link to an answer. Of course, I'm totally willing to be convinced that it is adequate standalone. :)

Comment: @huon-dbaupp And also add a flag like when you add more than one type of SQL to a question you get a small warning box.

Comment: @Matt, that's a good idea too, but I'm most concerned about users coming in from google etc., looking for answers: mistagged questions like that are easier to manage, as they can just be retagged. It'd be great to help as much as possible the "hidden" people who read others' questions, not ask them.

Comment: @huon-dbaupp incorrect assumption of tags, I imagine, is common place when "Google users" are reading questions, but thats the nature of a new user. Much like people wanting to "SELECT TOP 1 in Oracle SQL" and coming to the site from a Google search of "SELECT TOP 1 SQL"

Comment: One issue with specific versions is that a lot of questions don't indicate what version they apply to. We *could* try to see when each version was released and make a best-guess effort, but it might just be safer to tag everything with a "before 1.0" tag, if we choose this path.

Comment: @Shepmaster Yeh the initial tagging may be difficult, unless the OP and other experts can wade in

Answer (score 13):

(Disclosure: I'm also an occasional contributor to Rust)

I'd like something to this effect to happen, since this makes a lot of Stack Overflow answers less useful.

The ideal thing to do is to fix all the answers, though.

I think the best way to achieve this is the post notice system.

[image]

The only ones in built in the system are these:

[image]

Sites have had custom post notices added, though I don't recall any past situation where a rather specific post notice like this was added.

Comment: Related meta.se post: [_What is a better way to mark answers as obsolete?_](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244134/what-is-a-better-way-to-mark-answers-as-obsolete)

Comment: I think this isn't likely to happen, and isn't really the right way to do it.  Moderators won't necessarily have the time or the knowledge to mark questions this way.  Use the tools we have, which manage perfectly fine for things like [tag:php] and such which sometimes have significant versions breaks.

Comment: Your declaration should be rather something completely opposite to *disclaimer* ;o

Comment: @BartoszKP: I assume the term that was intended is "disclosure".  (If we both agree, I think that makes it safe to edit)

Comment: @BenVoigt Right, done :)

Answer (score 3):

I also propose version tags, but instead not be for a specific version, but rather a series. We already have this with `python-2.x` and `python-3.x`

I propose tagging things similarly. Have a new `rust-0.x` and `rust-1.x` tag, as well as keeping the original `rust` tag. Go through the rust tag and add rust-0.x tags where it can be easily determined, new questions can optionally append the rust-1.x tag. This would also be useful if eventually there is a rust-2.x in the future

Comment: Maybe SO could add a warning automatically if a question is tagged with a version tag and there are newer/higher version tags available. Whether this is feasible probably depends on how existing versioned tags such as `python-2.x` are used up to now ...