# I made a drastic edit to an obsolete Question

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16267578/321731) applies to an obsolete (and pre-release) version of Rust, but the title is still relevant, so I re-purposed it. I was also motivated by it ranking high on Google. But it was reverted as too drastic (see [the revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/16267578/revisions)).

Was I too bold? Thing is, with the rollback, it's useful to no one (though the younger of the 2 Answers is).

Comment: Also of relevance: [Editing Rust questions/answers to reflect the fact they only apply to a deprecated version](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288033/155423)

Comment: A newer development is *[Introducing Outdated Answers project](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405302/introducing-outdated-answers-project)* (2021).

Answer (score 7):

It is inappropriate to come in and reappropriate someone else's question, answer, upvotes, Google juice, or anything else for a new purpose.  Even if no one seems to be deriving any benefit from the original post.

This goes to the heart of the integrity of the voting process.  People voted for the original content, not for your replacement.

Don't do that.

Comment: Is it better to delete that content (versus re-appropriating) when it no longer serves any purpose? Note that such content could confuse people or waste their time.

Comment: @Tshepang: See Shepmaster's link.  Adding a banner and link to a related question based in a newer version of the tools is ok.

Comment: @Tshepang: On the other hand, adding a link to a specific *answer* is not ok, since it appears that the original author is now promoting that answer, which is not true.

Comment: Pointing to the specific Answer helps because the obsolete one is Accepted, making it appear at the top. Also, the edit history is there for a reason.

Comment: @Tshepang: Adding a banner at the top of the accepted answer pointing out how old it is, is helpful.  But do not point at a different answer, let the voters and readers decide which other answer is best.

Comment: Ok, I will do that.

Comment: @Tshepang: It's also ok to leave a *comment*, in your own name, under the accepted answer.  That way it is clear that you, not the answer author, are recommending a different answer.

Comment: Authors are notified when their Posts are modified, so I imagine that if they don't like the Edit, they would revert it themselves.

Comment: @Tshepang: That's creating extra work for the original author; don't do that.

Comment: It's something of a responsibility for them to keep their Posts useful for future users. Regardless, they are free not to act on that notification. Besides, aren't we curating a collection of useful knowledge here? Why leave no-longer-useful stuff untouched?

Comment: @Tshepang: I didn't say leave it untouched, I said you can add a banner that sticks to the bare facts ("This answer was written on a prerelease version of Rust").  Furthermore, you are too quick to assume that something is no longer useful -- people get stuck on old versions of tools, or want to know how a language has changed over time.  Finally, no it is not the responsibility of the original author to come back to the site and revert your improper changes.

Comment: This is a special case since this refers to pre-release (and unspecified) versions of Rust, and I'd be very surprised if anyone uses those at all.

Comment: Sorry about the "untouched" part

Comment: I've added a banner on the Question