# Clearing out pre-alpha and alpha questions

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

Much like [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288033/editing-rust-questions-answers-to-reflect-the-fact-they-only-apply-to-a-deprecat), we are at a point with [Aurelia](http://aurelia.io/) that v1.0 will be released very soon and we want to improve the quality of information available on StackOverflow.com.

We know that during the pre-alpha and alpha there were many questions asked that are no longer applicable or turned in to issues on Github that were fixed.  Because these questions have been around longer or received more attention they seem to turn up on Google searches more.

We don't see any value in leaving the pre-alpha/alpha stuff open because even attaching a pre-alpha tag and leaving it open would be confusing to new users who don't know to look for the tag.

We'd like to start closing the questions that the core team deems no longer feasible but wanted to clear it first so there isn't any confusion with the mods.

Sound good?

Comment: BTW this would not apply to beta or questions that have relevance or can be edited to provide value, simply to the ones that provide no real value due to a point in time issue that's too old to provide context or value.

Comment: So what is your plan, because I find that highly unclear. Are you suggesting that you go over all 1000 questions in [aurelia](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aurelia) and close them as off-topic: No longer reproducible?

Comment: Our plan is to start a github list for core team members to add questions they run across that fall in to the category listed above and have five checkmarks that a core team member can check off after voting to close.  We aren't asking for community help as much but rather using our knowledge to clean up the information on SO.com.  As far as which tag to use I think the no longer reproducible is probably the best to use yes.

Comment: If  you have 5 users that can close vote on SO and are going to do the clean-up that sounds all fine. If it is not to much effort it is maybe better to keep the list here on meta (as an answer) in case anyone starts wondering (and you could also point to it in a comment). See the [legal cleanup](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/295218/revisions) history as an example.

Comment: Keep in mind that *clear it first so there isn't any confusion with the mods.* is a bit strange as I doubt many moderators  would be subject matter expert. It is more what we as a community think about this, if that is what you ask.

Comment: How in any way are these questions off-topic? What close reason would these questions fit into?

Comment: Would it make sense to you if Microsoft developers closed (and/or deleted) all questions about versions of Windows prior to Windows 10?

Comment: Fair point @CodyGray, but it's a little bit different since the OP is talking about "pre-alpha/alpha stuff", not an officially released version of Aurelia. Still, I think Bart's suggestion of retagging is the way to go. But I'm just speaking in general terms, I know nothing about Aurelia, or how long this pre-release phase lasted. So feel free to ignore me. :)

Comment: I don't know anything about Aurelia, either. But if your alpha release was widely used enough to have questions asked about it on Stack Overflow, then you can't simply shove it under the rug and pretend it doesn't exist. Leave the questions be. Retagging is appropriate, and so is posting an answer that says "This problem was caused by *x*. It has since been fixed by release *y* (link to download it, with installation instructions, and any breaking changes)." That's a *good answer*.

Answer (score 10):

Questions don't get closed because they refer to old things. Questions get closed because they don't fit the scope of the site. And I don't think the situation you describe violates any of the "scope" requirements. A proper version tag is indeed where I would take this.

So I would advise against trying to close these questions as a form of clean-up. Create a proper version tag, fill the tag wiki with decent information about the version it refers to, and where people should look instead. And then apply that tag to all relevant questions.

As noted in the comments: if the question asked has a new up-to-date answer, you can always opt to provide such an answer, clearly stating what has changed and how it's done now. Add some links to up-to-date documentation - but keep your answer self-contained - and you should be good to go.

Comment: In addition, "saying pre-alpha isn't developed anymore, you should update" is Not an Answer

Comment: Is an alternative to answer such questions with *you shouldn't do that anymore with version x because it is deprecated. Instead use version Y where you would foo the bar over the baz*?

Comment: That could very well be @rene. Add an answer stating all that, sprinkle in some lovely links to up-to-date information (but keep your answer self-contained) and I see no problem with that.

Comment: But if the best answer is "This is not an issue on non-beta/alpha", why should we keep them?

Comment: If you're referring to something that was an explicit bug, by all means close it as "can no longer be reproduced" once it's fixed. But even then, given that these questions won't go away, make sure to state why it's no longer an issue. Other than that, go for an answer if you can give one, and/or tag appropriately

Comment: Not everybody updates to the new version of a framework immediately, even if it fixes bugs. Having information on old versions, including what bugs they have and possible workarounds, is therefore very useful. I can't believe I had to say that. "Can no longer be reproduced" is patently false. It *can* be reproduced if one follows the conditions described in the question, it is just fixed by updating to a later version.

Comment: Look from their point of view @CodyGray, if you allow people to continue using bug riddled software, you can't never know for sure if the question is a *valid question* or if it's a bug report. I presume these guys don't want another Aurelia become a Windows XP.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a bug tracker, so I'm not really sure how that is relevant, @Braiam. Furthermore, unless you resort to some really sketchy practices, there is no way to forbid (opposite of "allow) people from using older versions of software. Yes, it violates an ideal world, where everyone always uses the latest and greatest everything. But we don't live in that world. This is a Q&A site—if people still use the software, they're entitled to ask questions about it. Besides, this question was about *clearing out* old questions, not encouraging continued use.

Answer (score 2):

Lets examine both possibilities:

> turned in to issues on Github that were **fixed**

So, the question is not longer reproducible right? Close it.

> asked that are no longer applicable

Here gets a bit dicey, if the question itself wouldn't exist without using pre-alpha/alpha I would say "go for it". If the question itself would still exist but the answer changed, you need to edit the answer instead.

Basically, we want to keep up-to-date information and if the best solution is to stop using a bug riddled version, why should we cater these very localized issues?